# Pañchākśara Mantra in other Vedic texts

Tags: vedas, shiva, rudra

Is the Panchākśara Mantra (Namah Śivāya) mentioned in any Vedic text other than the Śrī Rudram or Śatarudrīrya of Yajurveda? , like , is it mentioned in any Brāhmaṇa texts or any other Vedic texts?

Comment: Nope, unless you consider Upanishads written in the second millennium as 'Vedic Proper' texts.

Comment: @Hiraṇyajihva thanks for the answer , the PanchākśAra mantra in the Samhita is Authentic though right?

Comment: I'd say yes but do note that parts the Sri-Rudram which is most commonly cited as the origin of the mantra is not vedic itself but it's a later hymn based off of the Rudra-Adyaya (Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́ 4.5)

Comment: Thanks! The Panchākśara mantra is most probably authentic as it is found in all Shākhās of the Yajurveda

Answer (score 1):

A scriptural reference is provided from the Pancha Brahma Upanishad.
It is classified as one of 14 Shaiva Upanishads, and one of the 32 Upanishads of the Krishna Yajurveda.
Pancha Brahma Upanishad belongs to the Black Yajur Veda. It deals with the panchanana or the fivefold aspect of Supreme Brahman, here equated with Shiva, but described as Pancha Brahmas. The Upanishad explains the significance of the five divinities Sathyojatha, Aghora, Vamadeva, Thathpurusha and Ishana, their respective attributes, functions and colors. The five fold aspect of Brahman or Shiva is represented by the five syllables hidden in the Panchakshari mantra, "Na-Ma-Si-Va-Ya." The Upanishad also reveals the fact that every form in the universe contains the five fold aspect of Brahman and that Lord Shiva exists in the hearts of all beings

In the Telugu language anthology of 108 Upanishads of the Muktika canon, narrated by Rama to Hanuman, it is listed as Pancabrahma Upanishad at number 93.

Quoted"
The existence in five shapes is called Brahma Karya (activity). After understanding Brahma Karya, Ishana is appreciated. After putting the fact all that is originating from Para Brahman in ones soul, the wise man experiences and understands that “It is me” and becomes Brahman as well as deathless. There is no doubt that the one who understands this Brahman becomes freed (emancipated).

One should chant the Panchakshara Mantra which is from Na to Ya (Namasivaya) and which is of the shape of five letters and is Lord Shiva’s body. After understanding the philosophy of the soul of Pancha Brahma, One should understand that every form is the form of those five. One who studies this knowledge of the soul of the Pancha Brahma would shine himself as Pancha Brahma. This Upanishad tells that Lord Shiva, who grants salvation to one, from this day- to-day life of the world, exists as witness without differentiation in the heart of all beings and is called Hrudayam (That which exists within).

Om ! May He protect us both together; may He nourish us both together; May we work conjointly with great energy, May our study be vigorous and effective; May we not mutually dispute (or may we not hate any). Om ! Let there be Peace in me ! Let there be Peace in my environment ! Let there be Peace in the forces that act on me !

Here ends the Pancha Brahma Upanishad, as contained in the Krishna Yajur Veda"
Endquote

Answer (score 1):

Maha Narayanopanishad XVI-1, which is from Yajurveda Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.16.2 has the lingam specific mantras.

> nidhanapataye namaH . nidhanapataantikaaya namaH |
> uurdhvaaya namaH . uurdhvali~Ngaaya namaH |
> hiraNyaaya namaH . hiraNyali~Ngaaya namaH |
> suvarNaaya namaH . suvarNali~Ngaaya namaH |
> divyaaya namaH . divyali~Ngaaya namaH | (Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.16.1)
> bhavaaya namaH. bhavali~Ngaaya namaH |
> sharvaaya namaH . sharvali~Ngaaya namaH |
> **shivaaya namaH . shivali~Ngaaya namaH |**
> jvalaaya namaH . jvalali~Ngaaya namaH |
> aatmaaya namaH . aatmali~Ngaaya namaH |
> paramaaya namaH . paramali~Ngaaya namaH |

I hope this clarifies your queries.